# Strange latch behavior in VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, simulation, fpga, synthesis

I've noticed a strange latch behavior in the following VHDL code:

```
 process (rd,addr) is                 
  begin
   if (rd)
    case (addr) is
     when '00'   => dout(15 downto 0) <= in0(15 downto 0);
     when '01'   => dout(7 downto 0)  <= in1(7 downto 0);
     when others => dout <= (others => '0');
    end case
   else
    dout <= (others => '0');  
   end if    
 end process;
```

The simulation is as follows:

rd = '1' and addr = '00' -> dout[15:0] = in0[15:0]

rd = '0'                 -> dout[15:0] = '0000'

rd = '1' and addr = '01' -> dout[7:0] = in1[7:0] and dout[15:8] = in0[15:8]

So it seems that a latch is generated for dout[15:8] by keeping previously value of in0[15:8], although I would expect dout[15:8] to be 0 as set when rd=0.

Any ideas why simulation behave that way?
Thanks,

Gil

Comment: Your snippet isn't valid VHDL. You haven't shown declarations, noting `rd` must be type boolean. Expressions `'00'` and `'01'` as choices aren't valid string or character literals. Your if statement is missing a then, both your if statement and case statement are missing the closing (delimiting) semicolon.

Comment: Well you don't assign anything to those bits of d0 in that case arm. Hence they must keep their previous value. (Matthew Taylor is correct about the sensitivity list, but that's nothing to do with the question you asked)

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate the [strange latch](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2fcw8.png) behavior after creating a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from you incorrect code and narrative. Please provide an MCVE. It might also be useful to provide information on your VHDL tool and it's version.

Comment: I'm guessing the difference between David's MCVE and the un-posted testbench is a delta-cycle where rd = '1' and addr transitions through 0 (setting dout(15:8)) to 1 (setting dout(7:0)). He also hasn't told us if this is behavioural or post-synthesis simulation; I would not expect code like this to behave the same after synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`in0` and `in1` are missing from your sensitivity list.

A sensitivity list in a combinational process should include all inputs. An input is any signal that is tested  (`rd` and `addr` in your example) and any signal on the right hand side of an assignment  (`in0` and `in1` in your example).